# ViewPager - fadingEdge only on left side showing

Tags: android, android-viewpager, edges, fading

I tried to set up an FadingEdge (horizontal) for my ViewPager, but the effect only shows on the left side. I want the effect on both sides
My code so far: 
XML:

```
    < android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:layout_height="130dp" />
```

Java:

```
    viewPager.setClipToPadding(false);
    viewPager.setPadding(0, 0, 15, 0);
    viewPager.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
    viewPager.setFadingEdgeLength(20);
```

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Remove `overScrollMode` line.

Comment: `viewPager.setPadding(0, 0, 15, 0);` remove right padding

Comment: already tried that, does not work